Can a multi-task model work on conditions for each layer?
I am currently working on a multi-task model that needs to handle car detection, damage segmentation and license plate ocr.
my idea was to only run the OCR layer when there is a license plate detected by the detection layer to maybe save computational power. My question is whether this is possible or not?
